# unpacking int + long long in python

Tags: python

I have to following strange problem while trying to read and unpack int32 + int64 in python 2.7.9

```
file = open('my_file.bin','rb')
s = file.read(4 + 8)
struct.unpack('IQ',s)
```

I get the following error:
unpack requires a string argument of length 16

Why is that ?  I=4 Q=8 IQ=12

btw the following works:

```
s = file.read(4)
struct.unpack('I',s)
s = file.read(8)
struct.unpack('Q',s)
```

Comment: I guess both unpack are then done on 8*8 = int64, can it be?

Answer (score 2):

Haven't used it myself, but according to the documentation, unpack() uses native padding of structs, as would a C compiler on your machine: apparently, you are running on a 64 bit machine. Prefix the format string `IQ` with an equals sign `=IQ` if you know the struct to be packed and follow native byte ordering.

Background: CPU's can fetch data aligned on word boundaries more efficiently than packed data, which require two fetch cycles (and DRAM access is slow compared to CPU speeds). Now that 64 bits is common (with 8 byte words), this helps explain why we need much more memory these days…

Answer (score 0):

It is alignment related issue. You can check in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment).